# Java prepared statement is not working?

Tags: java, sql, database, derby

I am writing a database program. But I am stuck with the Java prepared statement. The prepared statement doesn't seems to be working. I spend several hours to make it work but still same result.

```
 String sql = "INSERT into EDMSDATABASE.MESSAGE (title, subject, description, deadline) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
            try (
                    PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            ) {
                 statement.setString(1, bean.getTitle());
                 statement.setString(2, bean.getSubject());
                 statement.setString(3, bean.getDescription());
                 statement.setString(4, bean.getDeadline());
                  int affectedRow = statement.executeUpdate();            
                  if(affectedRow == 1) return "Success";

              } catch (SQLException e) 
                    { 

            } finally{



        }
```

Note that bean is a parameter

Comment: Define "doesn't seems to be working". What you expect to happen (and why) and what happens instead?

Comment: I am trying to add a new record to a table called EDMSDATABASE.MESSAGE using the prepared statement. But its not working. See the code snippet.

Comment: You have to specify the arguments (title, subject etc) in order to work. Read about [`setInt()`, `setString()` and the rest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). Also, you have to execute it.

Comment: It seems you never actually execute the statement.

Comment: see the updated code snippet

Comment: Well, now execute the statement!

Comment: Still its not working. Even though the parmeters are correct

Comment: Where are you executing your statement? You don't expect that it will be executed after `setString` call, right?

Comment: Within the same block. int affectedRow = statement.executeUpdate();
                if(affectedRow == 1) return "Success";

Comment: @user1036645 you might want to use `e.printStackTrace()` (or anything to print an error message) inside your catch statement. there could be an error.

Comment: And what happens when you execute your query? Do you see any problems, exceptions? Oh wait, to see them you would need code in you exception handling blocks (in `catch` sections) which would print them, so consider adding `e.printStackTrace();` to see if there ware any problems with this statement.

Comment: The error occurs after executing PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

Comment: What is in the exception chain? http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using 1.7 .  If not please use version compatible logic.

Comment: Do you know which version is compatible?